# How do i assign a new value?

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to find a way where the user can enter decimal numbers not only whole numbers for the division part and I also need help to fix the multiplication part, it keeps displaying the wrong answer when I intentionally wrote the wrong answer, for me it kept saying "the correct answer is 140" when the question was 5 x 2, and when I write 10 it says its correct but if its the same question and I write 4, for example, is says wrong the correct answer is 140 to the 5 x 2 question please help? here's my full code, and please if you find any more mistakes I did please let me know.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name + "\nWelcome to your Math Quiz (no calculators allowed) \nPlease answer the following questions");

    int randVal1 = (int) (20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int randVal2 = (int) (20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int randomNumberAdd = randVal1 + randVal2;
    int randomNumberMul = randVal1 * randVal2;
    int randomNumberDiv = randVal1 / randVal2;
    int correct = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        String userAnswer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, randVal1 + " + " + randVal2 + " = ");
        int answer = parseInt(userAnswer);
        if (answer == randVal1 + randVal2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
            correct++;
        } else if (answer != randVal1 + randVal2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The correct answer is " + randomNumberAdd);
        }

        {
            randVal1 = (int)(20* Math.random()) + 1;
            randVal2 = (int)(20*Math.random()) + 1;
            String userAnswerMul = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, randVal1 + " x " + randVal2 + " = " );
            int answer2 = parseInt (userAnswerMul);
            if (answer2 == randVal1 * randVal2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");
                correct++;
            } else if (answer2 != randVal1 * randVal2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The correct answer is " + randomNumberMul);
            }
            {
                randVal1 = (int) (10 * Math.random()) + 1;
                randVal2 = (int) (10 * Math.random()) + 1;
                String userAnswerDiv = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, randVal1 + " ÷ " + randVal2 + " = ");
                int answer3 = parseInt(userAnswerDiv);
                if (answer3 == randVal1 / randVal2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
                    correct++;
                } else if (answer3 != randVal1 / randVal2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong!");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The correct answer is " + randomNumberDiv);
                }
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got " + correct + " correct answers.");

}
}
```

Comment: `int randomNumberMul = randVal1 * randVal2;` does not mean that the randomNumberMul is permanently “bound” to the values of randVal1 and randVal2.  That statement is executed once, and the values of randVal1 and randVal2 are read at that time.  If you change their values later, randomNumberMul will not change, unless you explicitly assign a new value to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please change your question name to something related to your problem, rather than something specific with your situation. Good luck! :)